# REST JSON response to VF page

Tags: rest-api, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the json string into meaningful data over a VF page.

Here's where I'm stuck...

```
public class callApi{

private final String serviceEndpoint= 'http://XXX';
public String Response { get; set;}
public String Headers { get; set; }
public Boolean cache;
public List<Data> data { get; set; }
public Provider provider;

public class Data {
    public String unique_id {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String title {get;set;}
}

public class Provider {
    public String pubDate;
    public String source;
    public String url;
}        

public void fetchmyData() {
    getAndParse('GET');
}

public void getAndParse(String GET) {

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC';
request.setEndpoint(serviceEndpoint);

request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Accept','text/html');


request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
request.setTimeout(120000);        

HttpResponse json= http.send(request);

System.debug(json.getBody());
this.response=json.getBody();
callApi temp = parse(this.response);
System.debug('@@temp'+temp);
List<Data> dr = new List<Data>();
for(Data d : temp){
unique_id = d.unique_id;
description = d.description;
unique_id = d.unique_id;  
dr.add(d);

}

}
 public static callApi parse(String json) {

System.debug('@@json'+json);
    return (callApi) System.JSON.deserialize(json, callApi.class);
}
}
```

And here's the VF page

```
   <apex:page controller="callApi">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Get News">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons title="News">
    <apex:commandButton value="Get News" action="{!fetchmyData}" reRender="myBlock" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="myBlock" columns="1">
            <apex:repeat value="{!dr}" var="line">
                   <apex:outputText value="{!line.title}" id="theValue"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I get the a proper response string in **temp**. But I'm unable to parse and format the values. I do get a proper string if I put the repeat values as "!response", but this is not what I need. I require the data inside such as unique_id, description and title. I get the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: unique_id at line 49

I'm new to REST API, a help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the response look like? Did you JSON to Apex it?

Comment: Yes, I used JSON2Apex. The response is fine. SHould I post that too?

Comment: could you post it?

Comment: here you go...http://pastie.org/10935308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got your data in property `List<Data> data`. You just have to find a way to map it to page.

Apex:

```
public class callApi {

    public List<Data> data;// { get; set; }
    public String Response;
    public class Data {
        public String unique_id {get;set;}
        public String description {get;set;}
        public String title {get;set;}
    } 
    public void fetchmyData() {
        getAndParse('GET');
    }
    public void getAndParse(String GET) {//
        this.response = '{  "cache": true,  "data": [{"unique_id": "997991","description": "Scotland v United Arab Emirates 212/5 *","title": "Scotland v United Arab Emirates 212/5 *" }, {"unique_id": "1041859","description": "Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers","title": "Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers"    }], "provider": {"pubDate": "2016-08-12T20:58:21.776Z","source": "Various","url": "http://cricapi.com/" }}';
        callApi temp = parse(this.response);    
        this.data = temp.data; 
    }
    public List<Data> getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
    public static callApi parse(String json) {
        return (callApi) System.JSON.deserialize(json, callApi.class);
    }
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="callApi">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Get News">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons title="News">
                <apex:commandButton value="Get News" action="{!fetchmyData}" reRender="myBlock" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="myBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="line">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!line.title}" id="theValue"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi @ilya-lepesh. It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using JSON to Apex I built this Inner Class to use, I like to instantiate `Lists` in my inner classes so they aren't null.. This may be a personal preference

```
public class SportsReponseData
{
    public SportsReponseData()
    {
        data = new List<Data>();
    }

    public boolean cache {get;set;}
    public List<Data> data {get;set;}
    public Provider provider {get;set;}
}

public class Data 
{
    public String unique_id {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}    
    public String title {get;set;}  
}

public class Provider 
{
    public String pubDate {get;set;}    
    public String source {get;set;} 
    public String url {get;set;}    
}
```

I then built a test run and ran it in Anonymous like so..

```
SportsReponseData result = new SportsReponseData();

String testJSON = '{"cache": true,"data": [{"unique_id": "1041859","description": "Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers","title": "Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers"}],"provider": {"pubDate": "2016-08-12T20:58:21.776Z","source": "Various","url": "http://cricapi.com/"}}';

result = (SportsReponseData)JSON.deserialize(testJSON,  SportsReponseData.class);

System.debug('result ' + result);
```

And it returned the response into this

```
[cache=true, data=(Data:[description=Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers, title=Amo Sharks v Speen Ghar Tigers, unique_id=1041859]), provider=Provider:[pubDate=2016-08-12T20:58:21.776Z, source=Various, url=http://cricapi.com/]]
```

I only tested it with one, but it should be able to handle a list of your nodes, try it out I didn't want to build the string out, I'm not sure why yours didn't work but I did build my object differently

Comment: Attempting your way...

Comment: Hey Eric, I understand what you mean to say. But my main concern is to display it on a VF page. I'm anyway getting a json response. Thanks for helping!